# Using DbConnection.GetSchema() to retrieve all but System Dbs

Tags: c#, database, system

I am using DbConnection.GetSchema("Databases") to retrieve a list of databases from a given connection, and that works as expected. However i want to sort out the system db's from this list, as they are not valid for what i intend to do with this list.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

**Can only restrict by Name when retrieving information from the "Databases" meta-collection using GetSchema(), which will NOT allow you to filter out System DBs.**

There is an overload that allows you to specify a list of restrictions on the data returned, which should allow you to filter out System DBs:

[DbConnection.GetSchema(String, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53he2tz.aspx)

[Documentation on Restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722.aspx)

[How to use the method in practice](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/15/2734.aspx)

Comment: Yes, i know those links! Unfortunatly the only restriction available for the databases schema is the name. Have i missed something?

Comment: No you are right, I assumed you would have the ability to restrict the Databases based on more than Name, but it does not seem like you can. If you are using SQL Server 2005 / 2008, you could retrieve the info you want from a system view using a query similar to: 
SELECT * FROM sys.databases where owner_sid <> 0x01

Comment: Or SELECT * FROM sys.sysdatabases where sid <> 0x01 on SQL Server 2000. I am not familar with other RDBMS systems but I would presume they provide similr system objects you could use.